# 16.04 Wifi / ethernet issues after updating from 14.04

Tags: wireless, 16.04, lts

After upgrading Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04 I'm having some issues with my wifi connection.

Check this out, from a wired connection (pay attention to response delay).

```
leo@nelson:~$ ping facebook.com
PING facebook.com (66.220.158.68) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from edge-star-mini-shv-07-frc3.facebook.com (66.220.158.68): icmp_seq=1 ttl=75 time=154 ms
64 bytes from edge-star-mini-shv-07-frc3.facebook.com (66.220.158.68): icmp_seq=2 ttl=75 time=155 ms
64 bytes from edge-star-mini-shv-07-frc3.facebook.com (66.220.158.68): icmp_seq=3 ttl=75 time=155 ms
64 bytes from edge-star-mini-shv-07-frc3.facebook.com (66.220.158.68): icmp_seq=4 ttl=75 time=154 ms
64 bytes from edge-star-mini-shv-07-frc3.facebook.com (66.220.158.68): icmp_seq=5 ttl=75 time=155 ms
64 bytes from edge-star-mini-shv-07-frc3.facebook.com (66.220.158.68): icmp_seq=6 ttl=75 time=155 ms
64 bytes from edge-star-mini-shv-07-frc3.facebook.com (66.220.158.68): icmp_seq=7 ttl=75 time=155 ms
64 bytes from edge-star-mini-shv-07-frc3.facebook.com (66.220.158.68): icmp_seq=8 ttl=75 time=156 ms
64 bytes from edge-star-mini-shv-07-frc3.facebook.com (66.220.158.68): icmp_seq=9 ttl=75 time=156 ms
64 bytes from edge-star-mini-shv-07-frc3.facebook.com (66.220.158.68): icmp_seq=10 ttl=75 time=162 ms
64 bytes from edge-star-mini-shv-07-frc3.facebook.com (66.220.158.68): icmp_seq=11 ttl=75 time=154 ms
64 bytes from edge-star-mini-shv-07-frc3.facebook.com (66.220.158.68): icmp_seq=12 ttl=75 time=154 ms
64 bytes from edge-star-mini-shv-07-frc3.facebook.com (66.220.158.68): icmp_seq=13 ttl=75 time=155 ms
^C
--- facebook.com ping statistics ---
13 packets transmitted, 13 received, 0% packet loss, time 12001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 154.211/155.791/162.531/2.067 ms
```

But when I switch to WiFi:

```
leo@nelson:~$ ping facebook.com
PING facebook.com (66.220.158.68) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from edge-star-mini-shv-07-frc3.facebook.com (66.220.158.68): icmp_seq=1 ttl=79 time=323 ms
64 bytes from edge-star-mini-shv-07-frc3.facebook.com (66.220.158.68): icmp_seq=2 ttl=79 time=361 ms
64 bytes from edge-star-mini-shv-07-frc3.facebook.com (66.220.158.68): icmp_seq=3 ttl=79 time=1008 ms
64 bytes from edge-star-mini-shv-07-frc3.facebook.com (66.220.158.68): icmp_seq=4 ttl=79 time=652 ms
64 bytes from edge-star-mini-shv-07-frc3.facebook.com (66.220.158.68): icmp_seq=5 ttl=79 time=999 ms
64 bytes from edge-star-mini-shv-07-frc3.facebook.com (66.220.158.68): icmp_seq=6 ttl=79 time=1010 ms
64 bytes from edge-star-mini-shv-07-frc3.facebook.com (66.220.158.68): icmp_seq=7 ttl=79 time=1003 ms
64 bytes from edge-star-mini-shv-07-frc3.facebook.com (66.220.158.68): icmp_seq=8 ttl=79 time=1008 ms
64 bytes from edge-star-mini-shv-07-frc3.facebook.com (66.220.158.68): icmp_seq=9 ttl=79 time=420 ms
64 bytes from edge-star-mini-shv-07-frc3.facebook.com (66.220.158.68): icmp_seq=10 ttl=79 time=266 ms
64 bytes from edge-star-mini-shv-07-frc3.facebook.com (66.220.158.68): icmp_seq=11 ttl=79 time=168 ms
64 bytes from edge-star-mini-shv-07-frc3.facebook.com (66.220.158.68): icmp_seq=12 ttl=79 time=1009 ms
64 bytes from edge-star-mini-shv-07-frc3.facebook.com (66.220.158.68): icmp_seq=13 ttl=79 time=1005 ms
64 bytes from edge-star-mini-shv-07-frc3.facebook.com (66.220.158.68): icmp_seq=14 ttl=79 time=471 ms
^C
--- facebook.com ping statistics ---
14 packets transmitted, 14 received, 0% packet loss, time 13028ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 168.777/693.596/1010.408/329.180 ms, pipe 2
```

I have 2 different internet providers with 2 different routers on the same place. It happens the same over both connections. I've also tried with other computer with Ubuntu 12.04 and works like a charm.

I'm having this problem since I installed 16.04

Aditional info: I've been using a wired connection to work because It's unusable over wifi... BUT from time to time (every ~20-30 minutes) the wired connection gets disconnected (it happens with both routers from differents ISPs I have).

Mi wireless card info:

```
leo@nelson:~$ sudo lshw -class network
sudo: imposible resolver el anfitrión nelson
[sudo] password for leo: 
  *-network               
       descripción: Ethernet interface
       producto: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       fabricante: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       id físico: 0
       información del bus: pci@0000:01:00.0
       nombre lógico: eth0
       versión: 06
       serie: 4c:72:b9:58:9c:95
       tamaño: 100Mbit/s
       capacidad: 1Gbit/s
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuración: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 ip=192.168.0.18 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       recursos: irq:28 ioport:e000(size=256) memoria:d0004000-d0004fff memoria:d0000000-d0003fff
  *-network
       descripción: Interfaz inalámbrica
       producto: RT5390 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       fabricante: Ralink corp.
       id físico: 0
       información del bus: pci@0000:02:00.0
       nombre lógico: wlan0
       versión: 00
       serie: 20:10:7a:8e:3d:66
       anchura: 32 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuración: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=4.4.0-34-generic firmware=0.34 ip=192.168.1.157 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       recursos: irq:17 memoria:fea00000-fea0ffff
```

As @chili555 asked, here is "dmesg | grep rt2" output

```
leo@nelson:~$ dmesg | grep rt2
[   14.104800] rt2800pci 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   14.105008] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00_set_rt: Info - RT chipset 5390, rev 0502 detected
[   14.109544] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00_set_rf: Info - RF chipset 5390 detected
[   78.812904] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Loading firmware file 'rt2860.bin'
[   79.015681] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Firmware detected - version: 0.34
[  105.903521] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[  106.351522] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[  106.799553] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[  107.247543] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[  107.759574] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[  108.211584] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[  108.727599] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[  109.555615] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[  148.965666] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[  149.413726] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[  149.925810] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[  150.777953] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[  367.323945] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[  368.171986] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[  368.944044] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[  369.448049] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[  469.630931] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[  470.478973] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[  470.931053] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[  471.387076] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[  471.843081] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[  472.291140] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[  472.739165] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[  473.191144] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[  473.691199] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[  474.191255] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 1191.044092] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 1191.816158] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 1192.316182] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 4549.926258] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 5030.979039] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 5031.427145] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 5031.883092] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 5032.655142] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 7430.737637] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 7431.185659] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 7432.033748] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 7432.497744] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 7432.997769] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 7433.497799] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[10551.963800] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
```

Added iwconfig requested by Jeremy31

```
nelson@nelson:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eno1      no wireless extensions.

enp0s19f2u5  no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"Liit"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 54:BE:F7:61:84:25   
          Bit Rate=11 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=43/70  Signal level=-67 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:1637  Invalid misc:528   Missed beacon:0
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the result of: `dmesg | grep rt2`

Comment: @chili555 done!

Comment: As an experiment, please turn off wireless N in the router and reboot the router and the computer and see if the dozens of flush_queue messages remain. Set the router to Auto B and G; not B, G and N. If it doesn't help, you can always switch back.

Comment: I cannot access the router settings. The two ISP I have don't allow that. Btw, I have another computer with the same hardware setup but running Windows and works fine.

Comment: I regret that I have no other suggestions. Hopefully, someone else will see your question and answer.

Comment: Hey @chili555 , I've found this old question http://askubuntu.com/questions/178547/connection-drops-out-regularly-with-a-ralink-rt2800?rq=1 and I'm trying to do same. I've downloaded the last "backports" version (4.4.2) from kernel.org but there is no scripts/driver-select there...  could you help me out?

Comment: Please edit to add results for `iwconfig`

Comment: @Jeremy31 added!

Comment: did you try rfkill -a ?

Comment: I didn't. Could you tell me the whole syntax?

Comment: I think I might find another router to test with (one that you can get into).  Then inside that router I think you will find a way to turn on and look at an error log to tell you what the router is seeing which might help understand the nature of the problem and might possibly give you a clue as to what is happening.

Comment: I can bring to the office another router for testing purposes. It's a TP-link which info (and where should I get it) may I look for?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you try a driver parameter. From the terminal:

```
sudo -i
echo "options rt2800pci nohwcrypt=Y"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/rt2800pci.conf
exit.
```

Reboot. Any improvement? Check the message log:

```
dmesg | grep rt2
```

Are the errors, warnings, etc., such as you posted above, better, the same or worse?

If you wish to try to compile *backports*, I suggest:

```
cd ~/Downloads/backports-4.2.2-1
```

Or wherever you downloaded the package, if not Downloads.

```
make defconfig-wifi
make
sudo make install
```

The command 'make' takes a long time in this instance. Please be patient. Reboot. Any improvement? Check the message log:

```
dmesg | grep rt2
```

Comment: I tried the driver parameters, rebooted and it was exactly the same. I've tried to compile backports and "make deconfig-wifi" throws an error: nelson@nelson:~/Descargas/backports-4.4.2-1$ make deconfig-wifi
make[1]: *** No hay ninguna regla para construir el objetivo 'deconfig-wifi'.  Alto.
Makefile:40: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'deconfig-wifi'
make: *** [deconfig-wifi] Error 2 in english would be "There is no rule to construct the object 'deconfig-wifi'. I really appretiate your help.

Comment: It is not deconfig; it is *defconfig*. Please try again.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying again. New info: I connected my phone and shared the 4G connection through USB and it doesn't get disconnected every time as the wired ethernet does. Don't know if it helps. I will update when the backports installation finishes.

Comment: backports install was ok, but I'm still experiencing the issue.

Comment: I regret that I have no other suggestions.

Comment: For you to know, yesterday updates solved my problem. I was planning to downgrade today, but luckily I don't need it anymore. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 1):

Power Management is enabled on the wireless card.  To disable at boot

```
sudo -H gedit /lib/systemd/system/wifi-power-management-off.service
```

Enter the following

```
[Unit]
Description=Disable power management for wlan0
Requires=sys-subsystem-net-devices-wlan0.device
After=network.target
```

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStartPre= /bin/sleep 25
ExecStart=/sbin/iwconfig wlan0 power off

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Save file, exit gedit and then

```
systemctl enable wifi-power-management-off.service
```

This may prompt for your password twice, Reboot

If you have issues after suspend/sleep then you also need to

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/systemd/system/root-resume.service
```

Enter

```
[Unit]
Description=Turn off wlan power management
After=suspend.target
```

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStartPre= /bin/sleep 25
ExecStart= /sbin/iwconfig wlan0 power off

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target

And activate with

```
sudo systemctl enable root-resume
```

Source of the sleep/suspend fix is https://askubuntu.com/a/614245/300665

Comment: I tried but it didn't worked. http://i.imgur.com/GOZJitO.png I'm thinking on downgrading to 14.04 until this issue gets fixed. Thanks for the support anyway.

Comment: Does `iwconfig` show power management off?

Comment: Hmm I didn't check it. It's still on. I double-checked the steps again and re-run the commands + rebooted and it's still on. What's going on? Thanks.

Comment: The sleep timer might need to be increased, you can test with `sudo sed -i 's/sleep 20/sleep 60/' /lib/systemd/system/wifi-power-management-off.service` and reboot

Comment: For you to know, yesterday updates solved my problem. I was planning to downgrade today, but luckily I don't need it anymore. Thanks for the support.

Comment: @NelsonGaldemanGraziano I wonder what exactly was updated and how many other users might benefit from that knowledge. If you every find out can you post your own answer and mark it as solved? Or perhaps someone else knows and can answer for everyone interested, including hardworking posters of answers here.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix after a day of testing I realized that the update only solved part of the problem. Now the connection doesn't get disconnected every 10 minutes, BUT the 1000ms ping delay is still there... let's see if there is any new update in the next few days... I don't know exactly what they updated... but I saw a "network" packet on the automatic updates details, just after the update the connection didn't get disconnected any more.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to blacklist the r8169 driver and try installing the  r8168 driver r8168-dkms from the universe repository. [Package details](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/r8168-dkms)

If this doesn't resolve your wired connection issues try replacing the patch cable as it may have an intermittent short.

As far as the wireless is concerned you should try [2011_1007_RT5390_RT5392_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO updated to work with Linux kernel 3.8 and above.](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/r8168-dkms) Installation instructions are on the same page. I will replicate them here if you see value in that.

Edit: As reported by @Nelson Galdeman Graziano, It appears that a recent update resolved this issue. So the first thing to try is `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt upgrade`

Source:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=r8168&searchon=names&suite=xenial&section=all

Comment: I've just tried this, then I rebooted and pinged facebook.com and it still has ~1000ms over wifi connection. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Is the wired connection more stable? Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: With wired connection the ping is normal, but the LAN connetion gets disconnected every ~10 minutes.

Comment: @NelsonGaldemanGraziano updated answer

Comment: @NelsonGaldemanGraziano updated answer to cover RT5390

Comment: For you to know, yesterday updates solved my problem. I was planning to downgrade today, but luckily I don't need it anymore. Thanks for the support.