# Wifi keeps disconnecting in Ubuntu 16.04 on HP laptop

Tags: networking, wireless

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my HP laptop
But WiFi just keeps disconnecting after some time and I have to disable the networking and then re-enable it to reconnect.
Please help

```
09:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
```

Result for iwconfig:

```
sohan@sohan-PC:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.
wlo1      IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"OprimoUx"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 14:CC:20:34:77:6E   
      Bit Rate=120 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on
      Link Quality=53/70  Signal level=-57 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:24   Missed beacon:0

enp8s0    no wireless extensions.
```

Result for dmesg | grep rt2800

```
[    9.928496] rt2800pci 0000:09:00.0 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
```

result of this command
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && \
chmod +x wireless-info && \
./wireless-info

[Check please](http://pastebin.com/eaE9Ax8f)

Comment: Please edit the question to include results for `iwconfig; dmesg |  grep rt2800`

Comment: I updated the question with the requested command results , Please help @Jeremy31

Comment: Possible duplicate of [16.04 Wifi / ethernet issues after updating from 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/815891/16-04-wifi-ethernet-issues-after-updating-from-14-04)  Just replace wlan0 with wlo1 in the files as I suspect power management for wireless is part of the problem

Comment: I have turned power management off . But that didn't fix my problem @Jeremy31

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/a/425180/300665 and edit to post results or use pastebin.com

Comment: I have edited the post , please check @Jeremy31

Comment: Can you change the wifi routers channel to either 1 or 9?

Comment: I don't know how to :( . Can you give any link or video for doing that ? @Jeremy31

Comment: You would have to check the documentation for your router

Comment: I think there was problem with my network manager . I installed WICD and that's working fine for me :) .
Thanks for your help @Jeremy31

Comment: Did you uninstall or disable network manager?  If you did, the issue was likely network manager enabling power management on the wireless

Comment: I just disable wifi from network manager

Comment: Does `iwconfig` now show power management off?

Comment: Yes , it shows power management off @Jeremy31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there was problem with my network manager . I installed WICD from the Ubuntu Software store and that's working fine for me :)
Thanks for the help :)